# Backbone.js and Dynamic form generation

Tags: backbone.js, form-generator

This is the design question. Please suggest me .

We are using backbone.js framework. We have a requirement of heavy dynamic form generation ( May be of several dynamic bootstrapform wizards ).

In order to handle the form validation and submit method, I have to append the javascript code into the html code. Is this correct ?

Is there any better way to write ?

Thanks,
Raja K

Answer (score 2):

You won't have to append any js code into the generated html. What you're asking is typically done by creating a Backbone.View (which contains all of the interaction js code) that dynamically generates the form html and appends it to the DOM.

[Backbone forms](https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms) is a framework that you can use to make this easier, see below.

From the Backbone forms example (comments mine):

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
schema: {
    title:      { type: 'Select', options: ['Mr', 'Mrs', 'Ms'] },
    name:       'Text',
    email:      { validators: ['required', 'email'] },
    birthday:   'Date',
    password:   'Password',
    address:    { type: 'NestedModel', model: Address },
    notes:      { type: 'List', itemType: 'Text' }
}
});

var user = new User();

var form = new Backbone.Form({
    model: user
}).render();

$('body').append(form.el);
```

Then, you can listen to a [submit event](https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms#events) (and others) on the `form` object.

Comment: Yes, I have seen this. Can you suggest me how do I extend to you bootstrap form wizard and x-editable component ?